# Directing traffic to inactive pool on openstack

Tags: load-balancing, openstack, openstack-neutron

We have an openstack setup where a load balancer is directing traffic to the default pool (lets call it green_pool in this case). During deployments we place the new build on the inactive pool (blue_pool) and access it to complete the final testing before directing real traffic towards it.

Before we switched to openstack we had configuration in the f5 balancer which allowed us to direct our requests to the inactive pool to complete our final testing. However, now we don't have such configuration. Is there a smart way in openstack to somehow access the inactive pool?

I read about creating a floating IP pool with the below options but I'm wondering if there's a better way since we already have a pool:

`neutron net-create ext-net -- --router:external=True SPECIAL_OPTIONS`

`neutron subnet-create ext-net --allocation-pool start=FLOATING_IP_START,end=FLOATING_IP_END --gateway=EXTERNAL_INTERFACE_GATEWAY --enable_dhcp=False EXTERNAL_INTERFACE_CIDR`

Comment: This doesn't sound like an openstack question.  Are you asking how to configure an F5 that you...can't?  Or how to match traffic requests that aren't meant for you?  It's not clear.

Comment: I tried to clarify the question.